# PHP to input email to database

Tags: php, html, mysql, iphone, database

This is the site that I am trying to create the script for http://facechat.louisdickinson.com/
The idea is people can save there email to my database, and another button called "Start Call" will randomly select a email and call it using:

```
facetime://email@email.com
```

Effectively this will create a "omegle" style web-based facetime chat site.

I am new to MySQL and PHP and don't know where to start, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you asking how to use a database? Did you google for a tutorial?

Comment: I have found several half baked tutorials which for a while through me off track however I cant seem to connect with my Database, should I be using Localhost as the URL

Comment: You should be using whatever is needed. I don't know where your database is, but `127.0.0.1` is a safe bet whenever Mysql is on the same machine as the php script.

Comment: My database is on the louisdickinson.com hosting, and was created with PHPmyAdmin.

Comment: Then you should have a look at the configuration of PHPmyAdmin and see where that database is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, what kind of help do you need.. First of all, you should have a php script, witch can take the posted name/e-mail pair.
In this script, you should sanitize the posted values, than you can add it to your database with the following:

```
   $query = "INSERT INTO <tableName> (`name`, `e-mail`) VALUES ( '".$postedName."', '".$postedMail."' )";
```

On button press, you should have another php script, for selecting the random e-mail:

```
   $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <tableName>";
```

$max should be the query result.

```
   $random = rand( 0 , $max - 1 );
   $query = "SELECT `e-mail` FROM <tableName>" LIMIT $random, 1";
```

With this query you got a random e-mail.
Do you need more exact code? Please be more exact on what you need!

Kind regards, 
hotzu

Answer (score 0):

In php:

```
mysql_connect("host", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_selectdb("database");                   // '' for an auto increment column
mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('$email', ''));
```

And for more info http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp